# Why did I get `[three: command not found` from my Bash script? What to do about it?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I was testing a Bash script that accepts random arguments and noticed that it would say something like

```
./Var: line 19: [three: command not found
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
#!/bin/bash
$1 $2 $3

echo "The first argument does $1"
if [$1 >= 2]; then
    echo "$1 has 2 words"
else
    echo "$1 has unknown amount of words"
fi
#^First
echo "The second argument does $2"
if [$2 >= 2]; then
    echo "$2 has 2 words"
else
    echo "$2 has unknown amount of words"
fi
#^Second
echo "The third argument does $3"
if [$3 >= 2]; then
    echo "$3 has 2 words"
fi
#^Third
```

But it would continue to run the script, is there a way i can have it run without the "command not found" appearing? Or is this just an issue within my code that is making it do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you want to use is `[` (or `test`), not `[whatever`, so it should be (for example)

```
[ "$3" -ge 2 ]
```

instead of `[$3 >= 2]`, which generates `[three: command not found` if `$3` is `three`. Additionally:

- quote your variables;
- `[` doesn't understand `>=`, it understands `-ge` and other options;
- `>=` is a redirection anyway and it didn't get to the command, regardless if the command was `[` or `[three`. You now have a file named `=`.

In Bash `[` is a builtin. See `help [`, `help test`.